# Why does my table disappear when I use pagination?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I'm struggling with fancyTable pagination. The table renders all rows in two pages but the first click in my page 2 or 3 the table gets hidden and when I click again in that page the table appears with the data. What's my problem?
I'm using this fancyTable in my laravel project, and I render the results in a for each. I'm not using a js function to render the fancyTable. Anyone with the same problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#tabelaAssistencia").fancyTable({
    sortColumn: 1,
    sortOrder: 'asc', 
    sortable: true,
    pagination: true, 
    searchable: true,
    paginationClass: "btn btn-light",
    paginationClassActive: "btn-active",
    perPage: 15,
    inputStyle: "color:black!important;font-size:14px",
    inputPlaceholder: "Introduza o que pretende procurar..."
  });
});
```

```html
<table style="margin-top: 20px;" id="tabelaAssistencia">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="column" style="text-align:center">Entidade</th>
      <th scope="column" style="text-align:center" data-sortas="numeric">Numero</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- @if (count($results) > 0) @foreach ($results as $r) -->
    <tr>
      <td class="active-apply">{{ $r->entidade }}</td>
      <td class="active-apply">{{ $r->folha_obra_numero}}</td>
    <!-- @endforeach @endif -->
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.fancytable@1.0.20/dist/fancyTable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing table row tag. That may be a factor.

Comment: Also you seem to be closing your `if` twice.

Comment: I've fixed that, that may be a cause  yes but didnt worked .

Comment: You should fix it _here_ also. Don't make others stumble over those problems while trying to help.

Comment: Try using `@forelse ($results as $r) `rather than this if/loop thing here AFTER you fix the `</tr>` being outside the loop  ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures